# How do I install Informix ODBC on Windows Server 2003/2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, asp.net, odbc, informix

I installed the Informix Client SDK on my PC (32 bit) and on the server. I could create an ODBC connection on my PC easily, but on both Windows 2003 and 2008 (64 bit) I can't.

I don't know if there is a 64 bit SDK; maybe this is the issue. But I haven't found what to do.

I need to use ODBC since using the SDK by itself hangs IIS, and [according to this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1269896/2425034.aspx#2425034), the solution is to use ODBC.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the way.

The problem was that the server is 64-bit, and my workstation is 32-bit.

The IIS application is 32-bit, so the ODBC connection must be 32-bit as well.

To access 32-bit ODBC on 64-bit Windows, you should execute `c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe` instead of `c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe`.

Now I can add the data connection for Informix.

Hope this helps someone out there.

**UPDATE:** this is not working with Windows Server 2008 :(

Comment: Which version of CSDK do you have on Windows Server 2008?  Can you upgrade to 3.50.FC6 if you aren't already there?

Comment: Note that both 32-bit and 64-bit CSDK (ODBC) drivers should be able to connect to either a 32-bit or 64-bit IDS server via a networking connection.  The only time the client and server must use the same number of bits is when the shared memory connection mechanism is used ('olipcshm' or 'onipcshm').  Also check the support matrix; not all older versions of CSDK work on newer systems (like Windows Server 2008).

Answer (score 0):

64-bit Windows (all versions) supports both 32-bit and 64-bit executables and libraries.

The bitness of the ODBC consuming application dictates the bitness of the drivers it can use.  32-bit IIS requires 32-bit ODBC drivers, 32-bit Client SDK.  64-bit IIS can be set to run in 32-bit mode, in which case it requires 32-bit ODBC drivers, 32-bit Client SDK.  In default 64-bit mode, 64-bit IIS requires 64-bit ODBC drivers, 64-bit Client SDK.

32-bit ODBC Drivers are configured with the 32-bit ODBC Administrator.  On 64-bit Windows, this is `C:\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe`.  On 32-bit Windows, this is `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`.

64-bit ODBC Drivers are configured with the 64-bit ODBC Administrator.  On 64-bit Windows, this is `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`.  On 32-bit Windows, this does not exist.

System DSNs will be your best choice in almost all cases.  User DSNs are rarely the best choice.

Generally speaking, you want the latest version of the Informix CSDK regardless of the version of the target Informix instance.  Given that the target Informix instance is not on the same machine as the CSDK, the bitness of the CSDK and the target instance may but need not match.